# Detecting Kindle Fire version in Adobe AIR app

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flash, air

Is there a way to determine on which Kindle Fire type of device my app is running? I need to hide some features if the device is Kindle Fire (1st Gen), Kindle Fire (2nd Gen) or Kindle Fire HD 7 (3rd Gen).

One would think that flash.system.Capabilities or /system/build.prop would provide this info, but they don't. (correct me if I'm wrong)

I understand that getting this information would be trivial in a native Android app, but is there any way to do that in ActionScript under Adobe AIR **without building a custom ANE**?

Comment: look at the system capabilities class.  `flash.system.Capabilities.os` might be enough

Comment: If not, you can load in the android properties file (/system/build.prop) like this helper class does:  https://github.com/funky-monkey/Android-Native-Device-Info

Comment: /system/build.prop doesn't have this info.

Comment: screen resolution and dpi from the `capabilities` class would at least differentiate between the Kindle HD.  Not sure if the 1st and 2nd gen differ in screen size/resolution

Comment: The `build.prop` file should have a `MODEL` field that should be different?  Can you post your kindles build.prop file?

Answer (score 1):

The `flash.system.Capabilities` has many properties relating to the device.  the `os` property may or may not be specific enough to differentiate between the various kindles.

Chances are you use a combination of properties like `manufacturer`, `os` and `screenDPI` and `cpuArchitecture` to determine which Kindle it is.

If that doesn't work, then I know of 2 other ways you could accomplish this.

1. Find or create a [Native extension (ANE)](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/native-extensions-for-air.html)
2. Load the android properties file located at `/system/build.prop` and parse it for the value required.  There is helper class that can take care it for you if you don't want to recreate the wheel:
   https://github.com/funky-monkey/Android-Native-Device-Info